# What .* does in PostgreSQL ? and is there no necesarry to write AS to rename a variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, table-alias

I saw this query, and I'm still not really a pro in PostgreSQL. I want to know what does the `.*` after the `vi` and also i see that they rename tables without the as, it works but I wanted to know if its a common practice.

```
 select vi.* , coalesce(ordenes, 0)
 from vistas_por_jose vi
 left join ventas ve
 on vi.store_id = ve.store_id
```

Comment: Read this: https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-alias/

Comment: This query is very bad practice. Both using star and not using aliases is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select all columns from the `vi` alias, which is the table `vistas_por_jose` . Thus none of the `ve` alias (`ventas` ) will be selected. Unless `ordenes` is from `ventas`, at which point it really should be using the alias.